# Alternative to Thread.sleep() for performance?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, algorithm, spring-boot

I am doing a function in my Spring Boot application where in a REST request, I have to wait for a variable from the DB to have 'x' value and then return the response to the client.

I did it with `Thread.sleep()` in a while, but is it the best way to do it in terms of performance?

Code with Thread.sleep:

```
   while(!peticionTmp.isRealizada()) {
        entityManager.clear();
        peticionTmp = peticionesRepository.findById(peticion_id);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println("Iteración! --> " + peticionTmp);
    }
    
    return peticionTmp.isRealizada();
```

I saw what could be done with this:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor ();
     scheduler.schedule (() -> {
         / *
          * define work to be done inside this lambda
          * /
     }, diffTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

But I don't know how to implement it in the while.

The client sends a request, the spring boot application saves the request to the DB, now another program looks at the DB in search of requests, makes the service that contain the request and changes a field in the database of that request, the spring boot when it sees that it has been changed that field, I return the response to the client ...

Comment: This doesn't seem a good idea... who is changing the DB? If you're sure no external changes will come to the DB, you could instead modify your repository in a way that it can notify changes (i.e. observable) and this way you would instantly be able to tell when the desired state has been achieved.

Comment: I think your `Thread.sleep` approach is a correct one. However, the overall design seems incorrect. You'd rather use a callback when the result is in the DB and not leave the connection open to wait for the result.

Comment: @ACV "Spin-Wait" is commonly considered an anti-pattern. While sometimes it cannot be avoided, you should avoid it where you can. This seems to be an instance, where it could be avoided, but it needs some substantial effort.

Comment: You should use either long-polling on the API or implement client notifications, e.g. via websockets or using HTPP2. Blocking in a REST request is an awful idea.

Comment: *but is it the best way to do it in terms of performance* ... that is a nonsensical statement. What kind of performance are you worried about? "best" is **always** subjective. Note for example that (in terms of CPU cycles) your second option is way more heavier. Whereas the first solution means: you wait 3 seconds. Which might be way too long, so theoretically, that might add up to latency for some user . But we dont know any such details. You know. So, nobody here can tell you what is *best* for you.

Comment: @Marc Sances Who changes the DB is another service, this is why i wait until it changed...

Comment: @ACV example of a callback? DeferredResult?

Comment: It's a terrible design to me that two services are coupled via database, that service should send you a callback....

Comment: @Jerry Chin 

The client sends a request, the spring boot application saves the request to the DB, now another program looks at the DB in search of requests, makes the service that contain the request and changes a field in the database of that request, the spring boot when it sees that it has been changed that field, I return the response to the client ...

Comment: @ProgSnt6 DeferredResult will not help you. Basically you have 2 options: 1. Shift this polling to the client (jQuery and others have mechanisms to poll every x seconds for results) 2. Implement the push mechanism through websocket (where the server pushes a message to the client when the result is available). But basically you have to split the API in Query and Command.

Comment: @ACV With the implementation through websocket, which by the way i have never heard, does the client have to do a lot of work to communicate?

Comment: @ProgSnt6 https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Comment: @ACV Thanks, but client uses SAP ABAP :(

Answer (score 4):

As others have already pointed out, you have a very wrong system design in your hands, so you most likely have far bigger problems than performance.

Now, if you really must improve the performance of your existing brain-damaged system, then first of all you need to define performance.

What is performance for you?  Response time from the point of view of the client?  Number of clock cycles wasted on the server?  Number of simultaneous clients that can be served?

Your mind-bogglingly long timeout of 3 entire seconds seems to indicate that you perceive performance as clock cycles wasted on the server.  We usually choose very long polling periods when we want to greatly space out the moments of polling, so as to reduce the amount of work done per second.

But that was probably not your intention.  What you are probably concerned about is response time from the point of view of the client, since a timeout of 3 seconds means that the client will always wait at least 3 seconds, and certainly a multiple of 3 seconds. If you want to improve that, then the solution is simple: instead of `Thread.sleep(3000)` do `Thread.sleep(300)` or even `Thread.sleep(30)`. Now, that will increase the number of clock cycles wasted on the server; would that be a problem?  We don't know, because you have not defined what performance means for you.  But what we do know is that you cannot have everything: a brain-damaged system design will have to make compromises.

Adding information from the comments:

To fix this situation the first step is to give the server definitive knowledge of when the processing is complete, instead of having the server do polling to determine that. There are two approaches to this:

1. Have the server do the processing instead of an external application.
2. Have the server launch an external application to do the processing, ***and wait for that application to terminate***, so that as soon as the external application terminates, the server knows that the processing is done.

Then, you have a number of alternatives as far as the response to the client is concerned:

1. The server can keep the request waiting while the work is being done, and return a result at the end.  You are currently accomplishing this with `Thread.Sleep()`, but as I have explained above, this needs to go away, and to be replaced with the actual processing. If the processing ***must*** be done by an external application, then it will be replaced by `Process.WaitFor()`
2. The server can return a result saying "working on it" and then the client can keep calling the same or another API to poll for the results.
3. The server can make use of spring boot's DeferredResult.

If the client was a web browser instead of a REST client, then you would have two additional options:

1. The server can return a result saying "working on it" and then the client can use Ajax to receive notification that the work is done.
2. The server can return a result saying "working on it; please refresh the page to see if it is ready."

Comment: So what alternatives are there to this system?

If the client makes a request, he has to get a response that tells him whether it went well or not.

The request can last minutes but it is not a problem because the service that will be done is long and they already know it.

But of course while the program does the service, the spring boot has to wait for the response of the program (looking at the DB), or maybe there is another alternative ... (DeferredResult?)

Comment: By performance I was referring to the load to the server (cpu, ram etc)

Comment: The alternative is to first of all not have a separate "program" that "does the service" and instead "do the service" from within the server (launching an external program if need be, so that the server knows that the job is done as soon as the program returns.)

Comment: Then, as far as the response to the client is concerned, you have a number of alternatives: a) the server can keep the request waiting while the work is being done, and return a result at the end, or b) the server can send a result saying "working on it" and then use Ajax to notify the client that the work is done, or c) the server can serve a page saying "we are working on it, refresh the page to see if it is done".

Comment: And yes, Spring Boot's `DeferredResult` is also a very good option.  But as I wrote above, first you will have to give the server definitive knowledge of when the processing is done without involving any kind of polling.  Anything that involves polling is a bad idea.  Always.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much Mike!

The program that does the service is actually on the same server as the DB and the Spring Boot. The Spring Boot cannot perform these services, the program has to do it (vb6), I have already commented on this option to my superior but it cannot be for now.

Comment: The alternative a) you say, to keep the request waiting I don't know how to do it without using the thread.sleep in a while.
The alternative b) sounds good but we are using java, I can't do an ajax, but I could tell the client that every x time, check the spring boot if their request has finished ... but of course, they are using SAP and I don't know if they can do this.
Alternative c) is what I mentioned before.

Thank you very much

Comment: I amended my answer with information from the comments, taking into consideration your answers.  Check out the `process.WaitFor()` part, that's probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Excuse me,

But I think process.WaitFor () wouldn't work for me because I don't know when the external program will finish the job (there is no other option but the program to do the job). I have to check the DB if it has completed it, and it may take minutes ...

Almost everyone says Sleep is a bad idea, but I don't see a better option in this case ... As the Spring Boot rest is multithreaded ...

If the client accepts that he has to check the status of the request to see if it is finished, great, no problem. but if he don't accept it, I'll have to use Thread.sleep